# Check and get user's postcode once on start of app

Tags: java, android

I just want to get user's **postcode** once. I am looking to start my app, check the user's current position once and stop checking. In the event I am unable to get it due to no connection, then I want to just use last known position provided it exists. Can I get some advice on this please.

My following code keeps showing null for last known position since I don't have one. And I do not want to look for location change. Irregardless of whether I move or not, check for position on app start and stop checking after.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    Location location;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                1);
        return;
    }
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); // this is null and not ideal. I want current position. 
    Log.i("lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    Log.i("lng", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

    getPostCode(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
}

private void getPostCode(double lat, double lng){
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address = null;

    try {
        address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (address != null) {
        if (address.size() > 0) {
            String postCode = address.get(0).getPostalCode();
            Log.i("postcode", postCode);
        }
    }

}
```